# Adding Dynamic Headers in @HttpExchange

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm exploring Spring Boot 3. I created 2 REST services where one communicates with the other. Both are using Spring-starter-web and also imported Webflux. I found we can use *[@HttpExchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0-RC3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/service/annotation/HttpExchange.html)* (My previous experience is Spring Boot 2.6 and also used only RestClient). I have followed [this link](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/http-declarative-http-client-httpexchange/) to try.

I have added @HttpExchange. Created *HttpServiceProxyFactory* bean as well. Below is my code.
How to pass custom headers dynamically? Let's say I want to pass the authenticated user data in the header or some other values that are to be set dynamically.

**Client**

```
@HttpExchange("/blog")
public interface BlogClient {

    @PostExchange
    Mono<Course> create(@RequestBody BlogInfo blogInfo);
    
    @GetExchange
    Mono<Course> get(@PathVariable Long id);
}
```

**Configuration**

```
WebClient webClient(String url) {
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url).build();
}

@Bean
BlogClient blogClient() {
    
    HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory = HttpServiceProxyFactory
            .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient(blogBaseURL))).build();
    return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(BlogClient.class);

}
```

---

**Update**

I have figured out we can add *@RequestHeader* as a parameter and pass headers. [Similar to reading headers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers). But then the parameter needs to be added in all methods of all exchange interfaces which seems too much.

```
@PostExchange
Mono<Course> create(@RequestBody BlogInfo blogInfo, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers);
        
@GetExchange
Mono<Course> get(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers);
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this?

Comment: @CoderBro Not yet

Comment: Wondering why we can’t set the default header for all of our exchange method when create an instance of WebClient.Builder and setting the baseURL.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to set a global header whose value changes for each outgoing request, we can use the ExchangeFilterFunction. [[Updated Article]](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/http-declarative-http-client-httpexchange/#5-http-request-headers)

```
@Component
public class DynamicHeaderFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

  @Override
  public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest clientRequest, ExchangeFunction nextFilter) {

    // Create a new ClientRequest with the additional headers
    ClientRequest modifiedRequest = ClientRequest
        .from(clientRequest)
        .header("X-REQUEST-TIMESTAMP", LocalDateTime.now().toString())
        .build();

    return nextFilter.exchange(modifiedRequest);
  }
}
```

Next, register the DynamicHeaderFilter with the WebClient so it is invoked for each outgoing request.

```
@Autowired
DynamicHeaderFilter dynamicHeaderFilter;

@Bean
WebClient webClient(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  return WebClient.builder()
      ...
      .filter(dynamicHeaderFilter)
      ...
      .build();
}
```

Comment: But how do you set the values dynamically? This is during initialization. The username and password or token or some value I need to generate dynamically and not during initialization.

Comment: Updated the answer. We can use ExchangeFilterFunction in this case.

Comment: Please mark it accepted answer, it it solves your usecase.